# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC2\\x8E\\xC3\\xA9co...' for column 'announce' at row 1")

Tags: mysql, django

I am migrationg data from legacy database to new database. I tried code on local, it worked fine. When I am running code in production, for some fields, it's giving error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC2\\x8E\\xC3\\xA9co...' for column 'announce' at row 1")`

mysql version on local - 8.0.16
mysql version in production server - 5.7.33-

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Employee(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
           self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape'))
```

you need to encode with unicode_escape before saving as mention in above example self.name = str(self.name.encode('unicode_escape')) to accept any char

Answer (score 1):

**In Settings.py** 
My database settings has:
`'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}`

And change the table or field in which emoji needed support into the proper character set via this command:

**For Table** 
`ALTER TABLE my_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;`

**For field**
`ALTER TABLE my_table_name CHANGE my_field_name my_field_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;`

**or you go to phpmyadmin and do this**

And emojis are working fine. I put the SQL in a migration file so it's a part of the project with no need for extra database configuration manually, so it's all seamless.